# Getting in directive values entered in HTML markup

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/IQjeK6Ku5CmYpK22lgki?p=preview) I'm trying to obtain in a directive an array with values entered in a list of `<li>` within the directive declaration.

Given this directive declaration:

```
<directive>
  <ul>
    <li id="0">xxx 0</li>        
    <li id="1">xxx 1</li>        
    <li id="2">xxx 2</li>        
  </ul>
</directive>
```

The array should return something like this:

```
scope.array = [ {id:0, name: "xxx 0"}, {id:1, name: "xxx 1"}, {id:2, name: "xxx 2"} ];
```

This is my attempt (that doesn't work):

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
.directive('directive', function() {
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'AE';
    directive.template = "<div>{{array}}</div>";
    directive.scope = true;
    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.array = element.find("ul")[0].children;
    };
    return directive;

});
```

Comment: You're just setting the array to the list of `li` elements. You'll need to go through each one and pull out the id attribute and the content, create the object, and push it to the array. I must say this is a strange thing to write a directive for, but hey, party on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the updated plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/QtNkOGvLMdu3w6BS3tlB?p=preview

You can see the expected array in the template.

Required JS code:

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
.directive('directive', function() {
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'AE';
    directive.scope = true;
    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var newArray = [];
      angular.forEach(element.find('ul')[0].children, function(val) {
        newArray.push({id: val.id, name: val.innerHTML});
      });
      scope.array = newArray;
    };
    directive.template = "<div><pre>{{array|json}}</pre><span ng-transclude></span></div>";
    directive.transclude = true;
    return directive;

});
```

Comment: you should't change the `directive.template`, it should only show the array, not the list

Comment: Since the occurence of some html tags inside directive, your template '<div>{{array}}</div>' replaces '<ul><li id="0">xxx 0</li><li id="1">xxx 1</li><li id="2">xxx 2</li></ul>' unless you are not using 'transclude = true' and '<span ng-transclude></span>' in your directive.

Comment: If you want only the array then you can add display: none to the span tag '<span style='display:none' ng-transclude></span>'. Because ul, li tag should be there to form array